# Tomcat creating Hibernate SessionFactory in Infinite Loop in Spring3 MVC application

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

I have simple Spring3 MVC application. I am using Hibernate 3 with MySQL as database and Tomcat6. When I deploy my war file, first time the SessionFactory is created, webapp is initialized. But tomcat goes in infinite loop and keeps on creating sessionfactory again and again.(Even if no request is sent from browser) I tried a lot of clean up but not sure why this is happening. Please Help

So when I send a request to get domainList from db I my request is put on waiting , cuz tomcat is again creating sessionfactory. So once it is created , then data is fetched and sent as response.

**DomainDAO**

```
   public interface DomainDao {

    public void addContact(Object contact);
    public List<Object> listContact();
    public void removeContact(Integer id);
}
```

**DomainDAOImpl**

```
@Repository
    public class DomainDAOImpl implements DomainDao {

        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

            @Autowired
            public DomainDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
                this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            }


            public void addContact(Object contact) {
                 sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public List<Object> listContact() {
                 return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Domain").list();
            }

            public void removeContact(Integer id) {
                 Domain domain = (Domain) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                         Domain.class, id);
                    if (null != domain) {
                        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(domain);
                    }
            }
    }
```

**DomainService**

```
public interface DomainService {
     public void addContact(Object contact);
        public List<Object> listContact();
        public void removeContact(Integer id);
}
```

**DomainServiceImpl**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.dashboard.bo.DomainService;
import com.dashboard.dao.DomainDao;
import com.dashboard.entities.Domain;

@Service
public class DomainServiceImpl implements DomainService{


        @Autowired
        private DomainDao domainDAO;

        @Transactional
        public void addContact(Object domain) {
            domainDAO.addContact(domain);
        }

        @Transactional
        public List<Object> listContact() {

            return domainDAO.listContact();
        }

        @Transactional
        public void removeContact(Integer id) {
            domainDAO.removeContact(id);
        }


}
```

**Dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
            <context:annotation-config />
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.dashboard.bo, com.dashboard.bo.impl, com.dashboard.controller, com.dashboard.dao, com.dashboard.dao.impl" />
            <mvc:annotation-driven />
            <bean
                        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                        <property name="prefix">
                                    <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="suffix">
                                    <value>.jsp</value>
                        </property>
            </bean>



       <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />         

   <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            version="2.5">
            <display-name>HiberDash</display-name>
            <description>HiberDash</description>
            <servlet>
                        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                        </servlet-class>
                        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
            <listener>
                        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                        </listener-class>
            </listener>

            <context-param>
                   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                 <param-value>
                 /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
                 </param-value>
            </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**Tomcat Console**

```
> Jul 13, 2012 1:42:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
> log INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' Jul 13,
> 2012 1:42:13 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
> initServletBean INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization
> started Jul 13, 2012 1:42:13 PM
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
> prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace
> 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 13 13:42:13 IST 2012];
> parent: Root WebApplicationContext Jul 13, 2012 1:42:13 PM
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
> loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from
> ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:14 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport
> loadProperties INFO: Loading properties file from ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties] Jul 13, 2012 1:42:14 PM
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
> preInstantiateSingletons INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1357784:
> defining beans
> [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,domainServiceImpl,welcomeController,domainDAOImpl,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,messageSource,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager];
> parent:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bd06bf
> Jul 13, 2012 1:42:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
> INFO: configuring from url:
> jndi:/localhost/HiberDash/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:14 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure INFO:
> Configured SessionFactory: null Jul 13, 2012 1:42:14 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass INFO: Binding entity from
> annotated class: com.dashboard.entities.Domain Jul 13, 2012 1:42:14 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable INFO: Bind entity
> com.dashboard.entities.Domain on table domains Jul 13, 2012 1:42:14 PM
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
> buildSessionFactory INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory Jul
> 13, 2012 1:42:14 PM org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory
> newConnectionProvider INFO: Initializing connection provider:
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
> Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
> buildSettings INFO: RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.0.83-community-nt Jul 13,
> 2012 1:42:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO:
> JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.7
> ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} ) Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init> INFO: Using dialect:
> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory
> buildTransactionFactory INFO: Transaction strategy:
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory Jul 13,
> 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory
> getTransactionManagerLookup INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup
> configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional
> second-level cache is not recommended) Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Automatic flush
> during beforeCompletion(): disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Automatic
> session close at end of transaction: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: JDBC batch size:
> 15 Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
> buildSettings INFO: JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
> Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
> buildSettings INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: JDBC3
> getGeneratedKeys(): enabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Connection
> release mode: auto Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Maximum outer
> join fetch depth: 2 Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Default batch
> fetch size: 1 Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Generate SQL
> with comments: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Order SQL
> updates by primary key: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Order SQL
> inserts for batching: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory INFO:
> Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory Jul
> 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
> <init> INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Query language
> substitutions: {} Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: JPA-QL strict
> compliance: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Second-level
> cache: enabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Query cache:
> disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
> createCacheProvider INFO: Cache provider:
> org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Optimize cache
> for minimal puts: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Structured
> second-level cache entries: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Echoing all SQL
> to stdout Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
> buildSettings INFO: Statistics: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Deleted entity
> synthetic identifier rollback: disabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Default
> entity-mode: pojo Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings INFO: Named query
> checking : enabled Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init> INFO: building session
> factory Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance INFO: Not
> binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23
> PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome.*] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome/] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Root mapping to handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/getDomain] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/getDomain.*] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/getDomain/] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/getUsers] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/getUsers.*] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping
> registerHandler INFO: Mapped URL path [/getUsers/] onto handler
> [com.dashboard.controller.WelcomeController@18aeabe] Jul 13, 2012
> 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager
> afterPropertiesSet INFO: Using DataSource
> [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@18bff68] of Hibernate
> SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager Jul 13, 2012 1:42:23 PM
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean INFO:
> FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 9360 ms
```

Comment: did you try "static final" on your sessionFactory? that would lead you to the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally after whole week of pondering .. found the problem...**

**CORRUPT JAR FILES !! :(**

**Solution :**
Deleted all jar files of dependencies from m2 repository.
Did maven-update-dependencies. (from m2eclipse plugin)
Maven downloaded fresh jar files. Problem Solved!

**Problem was:**
When you are having bad internet connection / firewall or for any reason m2eclipse is not able to connect to maven repository, instead of giving error message, it creates an dummy jar file in repository (with size 8.98kb). This file is empty, and during maven build it uses these files hence no error at build. But at run time these files create lot of problems.